# Need Help on IMAP INBOX Search based on received date

Tags: imap

I am using a Open source IMAP  C# library IMapX (http://hellowebapps.com/products/imapx/).
When I trying to get the emails from INBOX it is taking lot of time. Is there any way to Filter inbox based on received date?

The below code is a sample. The search is based on UNSEEN. I want to filter based on received date is Greater than given date.

```
ImapX.ImapClient client = new ImapX.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
    bool result = false;

    result = client.Connection();
    if (result)
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Established");

    result = client.LogIn(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
    if (result)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Logged in");
        ImapX.FolderCollection folders = client.Folders;
        ImapX.MessageCollection messages = client.Folders["INBOX"].Search("UNSEEN", true); //true - means all message parts will be received from server

        int unread = messages.Count;
        string unseen = unread.ToString();
        button1.Text = unseen;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use IMAP search data item SINCE. Example: "SINCE 18-Nov-2011".
Or if you interested in UNSEEN too then: "SINCE 18-Nov-2011 UNSEEN"

Comment: if i want to get mail with in date range ,suppose like: want to get mail between 29-Nov-2011 to 30-Nov-2011 than what to do?how to write search query.

Comment: This is working code I derived via this answer: `imap_search( $this->mbox, SINCE "Wed, 3 Feb 2010 0:00:00" BEFORE "Sat, 13 Feb 2010 0:00:00")` php's `strtotime()` and `date('D, j M Y G:i:s')` are quite useful. FYI the above search for a gmail box and message retrieval takes about 20 seconds.

Comment: I have written like:new \PhpImap\Mailbox('{'.$mdata["server"].":993/imap/ssl}". $folder['shortpath'], $mdata["user"], $mdata["pass"], $dir);
                    $mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox($mailbox, 'SINCE "Thu, 6 Dec 2018 0:00:00"');
                    echo"<pre>";print_r($mailsIds);die; but it gives me empty array