# php imap how to get unread mails of the last 7 days using imap_sort?

Tags: php, imap

Is it possible to get the unread messages of the last 7 days. ? I have

```
 $result = imap_sort($imap, SORTDATE, 1,"UNSEEN");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
$date = date ( "d M Y", strToTime ( "-7 days" ) );
$search_criteria = "SINCE \"$date\""." UNSEEN";
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info, is there some doc for this? I am trying to do something like "last 5 mins".

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$msg = imap_search( $imap, "SINCE Mon, 12 Jan 2015 0:00:00 UNSEEN")
```

and check below link also

[Need Help on IMAP INBOX Search based on received date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165727/need-help-on-imap-inbox-search-based-on-received-date)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i already tried this method. 
I want to get only emails for the last seven days.

Comment: This answer is wrong; IMAP SINCE doesn't accept that time. The syntax in the answer linked to is right.

Comment: I already answered the question. I found the solution and i added it to this question.